# How to correctly schedule this 5 minutes Spring Batch Job? Why is it starting immediatly instead of waiting for the set time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application and I am finding some difficulties trying to correctly schedule a job.

I have this class where my job was scheduled:

```
/**
 * This bean schedules and runs our Spring Batch job.
 */
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("launcher")
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
    private Job updateNotaryDistrictsJob;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updateNotaryListInfoJob")
    private Job updateNotaryListInfoJob;
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * *")
    public void runUpdateNotaryDistrictsJob() {
        LOGGER.info("SCHEDULED run of updateNotaryDistrictsJob STARTED");
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(updateNotaryDistrictsJob, jobParameters);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    
}
```

As you can see on my **runUpdateNotaryDistrictsJob()** method I set this Spring CRON expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * *")
```

in order to start my **updateNotaryDistrictsJob** every 5 minutes.

The problem is that when I run my application in debug mode I can see that the job is immediately performed (it stop on the first breakpoint). It seems that it is not waiting the 5 minutes set by the cron expression.

What is wrong? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: I assume you are using EnableScheduling.  Could you try with 0 0/5  .  I mean in theory */5 should work..but just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cron expression `0 */5 * * * *` does not read as you expect. "It seems that it is not waiting the 5 minutes set by the cron expression.", this is not what the cron expression defines. The cron expression will run at second 0, every 5 minutes starting at minute 0, of every hour, which means that it will never wait 5 minutes after the service has started. As an example, if you started it at 10:22, it will run at 10:25.

If you really need it to wait 5 minutes after service has started, you should consider using `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000, initialDelay = 5000)`.